# How to use nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search to limit results at radius of 1km?

Tags: search, openstreetmap

When using https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&q=bahamas%20ponte%20nova&addressdetails=1&limit=3

I have exactly the result that I want.

But if you delete the name of my city "Ponte Nova", in the result comes up to references from Spain, but no results come from my city.

How do I get the results to focus on a given radius?

Comment: In English, please, or try your question at [pt.so]. Though due to the lack of code, this question is most likely off-topic.

Comment: We ask you to write in English or post a question on the corresponding StackOverflow language-specific page.

Comment: Please translate the title too. Also, I'm a little confused as to why this is tagged as [Java] and [php] given that it doesn't contain any Java or PHP code.

Answer (score 3):

Please see see [Nominatim API documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/).

According to section [Result Limitation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/#result-limitation) you can use `viewbox=<x1>,<y1>,<x2>,<y2>` and `bounded=1` to restrict the search results to a specific area.

Example: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&q=bahamas&addressdetails=1&limit=3&viewbox=-43.00804%2C-20.36925%2C-42.73699%2C-20.44969&bounded=1

Comment: Very... very thank you!!! I fully understood the concept.

Can you tell me how to calculate these starting viewbox limits from my current position?

Comment: These are just latitude and longitude. Calculating a bounding box around a given position is a different question but already has answers all over the Internet. See for example the answers to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/2951/23837

Comment: Why would end up in Brazil when both points are out in the south atlantic ocean. Where is the bounding box? Shouldn't they represent corners of it?

Comment: @lolelo Did you mix up latitude and longitude?

Comment: @scai Yes I did! I looked on them the wrong way when picking out google map coordinates. But I found a website which had them in correct order, opposite of mine so it started working: http://bboxfinder.com/#0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000